# Accordion not working

Tags: accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to use accordion. The function I'm using is

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

The function works properly but only if i add the libraries on the same page where i am using accordion.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

where as I download the css file and gave path in view.yml. But if i do the same for the js file (download them and give path in view.yml) it does not seem to work. I want to re-use them in many pages that is why i dont want to include web path in every page.

Secondly if i give path on the page, the bootstrap does not seem to work properly there occurs a clash or something. Give me solution for that. How do i avoid giving path in all the pages. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really clear about your question. The code you use is based on jQuery. If you don't have jQuery loaded the function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a shared view or a layout view that includes references to commons script files used on all pages. Then you can just include the script tag in that one spot.

For example, in ASP.NET-MVC, if you're using razor views, the '_Layout.cshtml' file should be referenced already in your '_ViewStart.cshtml' file. If not, you can just add a reference to a shared view in any file like this:

```
@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
```

Then just be sure to include the necessary script(s) in the _Layout file.

You can do something similar in php by simply adding an include statement to each view like this:

```
< ? php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Then just reference a copy of jquery or pull it from the CDN in the header.php file.

For more info try these links:
ASP.NET-MVC:  http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp

PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp